# SQL Join Based on Row condition

Tags: sql, join

I have a table as follow.

```
+--------+------------+------+-----------------+
| key    | english    | lang | translation     |
+--------+------------+------+-----------------+
| id1    | string1    | eng  | NULL            |
| id1    | string1    | rus  | russian_string1 |
| id2    | string2    | eng  | NULL            |
| id2    | string2    | rus  | russian_string2 |
| id3    | string3    | eng  | NULL            |
| id3    | string3    | rus  | NULL            |
| id4    | string4    | eng  | NULL            |
| id5    | string5    | eng  | NULL            |
+--------+------------+------+-----------------+
```

I would like to query in such a way so as to output following result

```
+--------+------------+------+------------------+
| pk     | english    | lang | translation      |
+--------+------------+------+------------------+
| id1    | string1    | rus  | russian_string1  |
| id2    | string2    | rus  | russian_string2  |
| id3    | string3    | eng  | NULL             |
| id4    | string4    | eng  | NULL             |
| id5    | string5    | eng  | NULL             |
+--------+------------+------+-------------------+
```

To achieve this I am currently making two db calls as follow

```
SELECT key, english, lang, translation FROM table where lang = 'eng';
+--------+------------+------+-------------+
| key    | english    | lang | translation |
+--------+------------+------+-------------+
| id1    | string1    | eng  | NULL        |
| id2    | string2    | eng  | NULL        |
| id3    | string3    | eng  | NULL        |
| id4    | string4    | eng  | NULL        |
| id5    | string5    | eng  | NULL        |
+--------+------------+------+-------------+
```

and

```
SELECT key, english, lang, translation FROM table WHERE lang = 'rus' and translation is not null;
+--------+------------+------+-----------------+
| key    | english    | lang | translation     |
+--------+------------+------+-----------------+
| id1    | string1    | rus  | russian_string1 |
| id2    | string2    | rus  | russian_string2 |
+--------+------------+------+-----------------+
```

and then combine the result of these two queries in code.
I am sure there can be a better SQL way of doing this.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.  It is also unclear why `lang = 'hin'` would return rows where `lang = 'rus'`.

Comment: `WHERE lang = 'hin'`? You mean `rus`, right?

Comment: sorry about the typo, fixed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is:

```
select t.*
from t
where lang = 'rus' or
      (lang = 'eng' and
       not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.key = t.key and t2.lang = 'rus');
```

A more general approach -- for more languages -- uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by key order by case lang when 'rus' then 1 when 'eng' then 2 else 3 end) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: or even something like `...ORDER BY array_position(...)`

Answer (score 1):

With `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
select distinct key, english,
  first_value(lang) over (partition by key, english 
    order by case when lang = 'rus' and translation is not null then 1 when lang = 'eng' then 2 else 3 end) lang,
  first_value(translation) over (partition by key, english 
    order by case when lang = 'rus' and translation is not null then 1 when lang = 'eng' then 2 else 3 end) translation
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0d11264e91a11b779848985a27122972).
Results:

```
> key | english | lang | translation    
> :-- | :------ | :--- | :--------------
> id1 | string1 | rus  | russian_string1
> id2 | string2 | rus  | russian_string2
> id3 | string3 | eng  | null         
> id4 | string4 | eng  | null         
> id5 | string5 | eng  | null
```